# what happens if I await a task that is already running or ran?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

There is a Task variable and lets say the task is running right now.. by executing the following line.

```
await _task;
```

I was wondering what happens when I write this code:

```
await _task;
await _task;
```

would it execute the task twice ? Or throw an exception because it has already run ?

Comment: Why don't you try it? It's not hard to test.

Comment: The key insight to have here is that *await does not run a task*.  Await *asynchronously waits for a task to be finished*. Hence the name "await". There is a persistent myth that await starts a task, but of course it does not; you already have a started task in hand by the time you await it.

Comment: The real eye opener for me was the concept of 'continuations'. I think without that insight, it's hard to grasp 'await'.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> would it execute the task twice ? Or throw an exception because it has
>   already run ?

No and no. The only thing `await` does is call `Task.GetAwaiter`, it does not cause anything to run. If the task already ran to completion, it will either extract the value if it is a `Task<T>`, or run synchronously to the next line if it is a `Task`, since there is an optimization for already completed tasks.

A simple demo:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var foo = FooAsync();
    await foo;
    await foo;

    var bar = BarAsync();
    var firstResult = await bar;
    var secondResult = await bar;

    Console.WriteLine(firstResult);
    Console.WriteLine(secondResult);
}

public async Task FooAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
}

public async Task<int> BarAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return 1;
}
```

If you drill down to the state machine itself, you'll see this:

```
this.<foo>5__1 = this.<>4__this.FooAsync();
taskAwaiter = this.<foo>5__1.GetAwaiter();
if (!taskAwaiter.IsCompleted)
{
    this.<>1__state = 0;
    this.<>u__1 = taskAwaiter;
    M.<FooBar>d__0 <FooBar>d__ = this;
    this.<>t__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter, M.<FooBar>d__0>
                                                    (ref taskAwaiter, ref <FooBar>d__);
    return;
}
```

This optimization first checks the completion of the task. If the task isn't complete, it will call `UnsafeOnCompleted` which will register the continuation. If it is complete, it breaks the `switch` and goes to:

```
this.<>1__state = -2;
this.<>t__builder.SetResult();
```

Which sets the result for the underlying `Task`, and that way you actually get the value synchronously.

Comment: And it should be noted that *this is a good thing*. One of the tricky parts about asynchronous code is that most asynchronous operations can in fact finish synchronously - and that's a separate case you have to handle, because your asynchronous callback is *not* going to be called in that case. `await` hides all this complexity from you, and it allows you to `await` the same task in ten different places (very useful for e.g. asynchronous lazy initialization).

Comment: can I be assured that the method pointed by task wont be executed twice even if the task is running or ran already ?

Comment: @BilalFazlani Yes, you can. If the `Task` is already completed, it will simply unwrap the result.

Comment: @BilalFazlani - are you aware that there's a specific class designed to assist with lazy initialization? - [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 20):

I threw together this quick test:

```
var i = 0;
var task = Task.Run(() => { i++; Console.WriteLine(i); return i; });

var x = await task;
var y = await task;

Console.WriteLine(x);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

It writes:

```
1
1
1
```

So, clearly, the task only runs once.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. That was really helpful